# What species is Pannya?

Tags: mashiroiro-symphony

In Mashiroiro Symphony, Pannya is a cute cat-like creature. However, at least in the anime (unless I missed it), her actual species is not named. The anime also has plenty of ordinary cats, so it doesn't seem like Pannya is just a chibified version of a cat. Furthermore, there seem to be other animals of the same species.

[image]

(Note: Pannya is the one on the left)

Is Pannya's species ever given a name? I'm fairly sure that it isn't named in the anime, so I'm mostly looking for confirmation from the manga and/or visual novel.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe that Pannya is not a real species. It is likely a [RidiculouslyCuteCritter](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RidiculouslyCuteCritter) added as a [SeriesMascot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SeriesMascot), possibly for the purpose of making the series more recognizable.

Take note at how Pannya always appears hanging on the characters in the title of the series.

[image: Look forward to next week's broadcast]

[image: OP]